Is there some way to convert a rear disc brake bike to any type of rim brakes
I have a Cannondale Quick 6. Its an awesome bike but I dislike the disc brakes.
I think it comes with a hole in the fork for mounting a front rim caliper brake.
The frame has the crossbridge part in the rear but it has a threaded insert I believe might be for fitting a fender. It's not the through-hole for a rear caliper brake.
Is there some kind of adapters, special beake fitting systems or something around that I can use to fit any type of rim braking system in the rear of this bike?

According to the specs, the Quick 6 comes with rim brakes, the 5 with bad mechanical disc brakes (entry level mechanical disc brakes are rarely good). Changing to hydraulic disc brakes is certainly worth trying, and straightforward comparing to modifying a frame.

You are correct. My bike is in fact a Quick 5. Sorry for the confusion. I thought of switching the pads and see if using a different compound helps. I know I would have to change to a different wheel. I was told the fork of the bike is steel, and I thought the thickness of the metal around the hole looks beefy enough to me, I  I will check the caliper hole and see if I can come up with any way to figure

Figure out if it fits before I just start buying things to try on for size

For the price of decent rim brakes and levers, I would buy Deore-level hydraulic disc brakes instead. When you consider you might need new rims to have a suitable rim braking surface, that prospect is the only one that makes sense. You could get SLX brakes or XT-level brakes and come out way ahead.

Just note if you explore the possibility of hydraulic disc brakes that the bike has road-style calipers (flat mount), but flat bar levers. Not a problem per se, they are cross-compatible, but important to know. The entry-level Shimano MT201/UR300 is very recommendable. There are also quality mechanical calipers, but they are now very niche products, and priced accordingly.

Caliper brake hole can be for something else too such as fenders and front lights. You have to ensure the fork is strong enough at this point to support a caliper. You also need to have a suitable caliper, there are different types of bolts there, and the reach of the caliper needs to be correct too. Considering that before disc brakes proliferated that caliper brakes were ultra-short reach almost always, and disc brake bikes have lots of tire clearance, it's very likely you won't find a caliper brake with enough reach.
Also the rims need to have brake tracks suitable for disc brakes. I always use DT Swiss TK 540 rims that have a brake track, even though I use them on disc brake bikes too. However, most bikes that come with disc brakes come with rims that don't have brake tracks and therefore cannot be used for rim brakes. The brake tracks need to be parallel and thick enough for long wear life, non-powder-coated (bare metal), and ideally there would be some kind of wear indicators too.
If you can ensure the fork is strong enough for caliper brakes, find a compatible caliper, and have compatible rims, then that's all you need. You just need to change your levers to rim brake levers. However, considering that Quick 6 seems to be a non drop bar bike and that caliper brakes are short pull, finding compatible levers could be tricky. You need levers compatible with cantilever and caliper brakes, and today most non drop bar bikes with rim brakes have V brakes, which have long pull levers.
